# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object(...)(...).once is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, quasar

Hi I need some help with these it says that

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object(...)(...).once is not a function
at eval (store.js?07a4:42:1)
at eval (index-6de4cbb9.js?4d2d:2453:1)

Here's my code:

```
import { firebaseAuth, firebaseDb } from 'boot/firebase'
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword,onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { ref, set } from "firebase/database";


const state = {

}
const mutations = {

}
const actions = {
  registerUser({}, payload) {
     createUserWithEmailAndPassword(firebaseAuth, payload.email, payload.password)
     .then(response => {
         console.log(response)
         const userId = firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid
          set(ref(firebaseDb, 'users/' + userId), {
            name: payload.name,
            email: payload.email,
            online: true
          })
     }).catch(error => {
       console.log(error.message)
     })
  },
  loginUser({}, payload) {
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(firebaseAuth, payload.email, payload.password)
     .then(response => {
         console.log(response)
     }).catch(error => {
       console.log(error.message)
     })
  },
```

Here's the part that is error:

```
  handleAuthStateChanged() {
    onAuthStateChanged(firebaseAuth, user => {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
        const userId = firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid
        ref(firebaseDb, 'users/' + userId).once('value', snapshot => {
          console.log('snapshot: ', snapshot)
        })
        // ...
      } else {
```

User is signed out

```
// ...
      }
    })
  }
}
const getters = {

}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters
}
```

i dont get it i still received this kind of error

```
<script>
  import { mapActions } from "vuex"

  export default {
    methods: {
      ...mapActions('store', ['handleAuthStateChanged'])
    },
    mounted(){
      this.handleAuthStateChanged()
    }
  }
</script>
```

this is my App.vue script

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tIi4.png)

[full-code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMlyk.png)

Comment: is this the right way to declare .once on this particular code?

Comment: Please copy the full code into your question as text, NOT as an image for a whole bunch of reasons (we can search it, we can copy it into answers, it can be indexed by search engines, we can see it without opening another window, etc...).

Comment: Also, your "full-code" does not show where `onAuthStateChanged` is called so it's hard to figure out what the context for that code is.

Comment: I don't know firebase, but the example of `.once()` on [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#properties_1) shows it working differently.

Comment: https://github.com/stephenj1998/instajobchat @jfriend00 here's my github project